# XSLT 2.0 function not executing

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have this template:

```
<xsl:template match="opf:manifest">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="unparsed-text('Styles/fonts.css')" regex='url\(\"(.*[^\"]*)\"\)'>
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:element name="opf:item">
                <xsl:attribute name="href" select="regex-group(1)"/> 
                <xsl:attribute name="media-type">application/vnd.ms-opentype
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="id" select="generate-id()"/> 
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('index.xml')//opf/(jpeg | scripts)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('index.xml')/numberGroup/entry/file"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The regex-group function does what it is supposed to do.
However, the generate-id() does not. XMLSPY Debugger stumbles: "error in XPATH 2.0 expression (not a node item)."
What do I do wrong?
(btw: generate-id(.) does the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `analyze-string` the current context item (`.`) is a *string* (the current matching or non-matching substring), not a node, so you can't pass it to `generate-id`.  If what you want is the generated ID of the node that the current template matched then you need to cache it in a variable outside the `analyze-string` and then use that variable with `generate-id`:

```
<xsl:variable name="dot" select="." />
<xsl:analyze-string select="unparsed-text('Styles/fonts.css')" regex='url\(\"(.*[^\"]*)\"\)'>
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <!-- ... -->
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="generate-id($dot)"/>
```

(or indeed just cache the ID itself `<xsl:variable name="theId" select="generate-id()" />`)

Comment: Then every <item> will get the same id, I'm afraid... So I'll be better off with "concat('fontId', position())"

Comment: @Erik indeed, `position()` inside `analyze-string` gives you the position in the "list of matching and non-matching substrings" so in this case it would give you `fontId2`, `fontId4`, etc.